# Angular Material Dialog - Edit value on dialog should not update on table row automatically

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I am not much familiar with Angular Material. But in my new application, I am using it and now I am facing some challenges with dialog.

I have a table with multiple rows and there I want to do an edit on it.
When I click on Edit a dialog box should open and I should able to edit the data. 
There are two action buttons say **Cancel** and **Update**.

Update should save the data, close the dialog box and display updated data on the table.

Cancel should simply close the dialog box.

```
<div *ngFor="let attachment of doc.attachments; let i = index" fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="row" >
    <div fxFlex="auto">{{attachment.note}}</div>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="editAttachmentNote(attachment)"> 
         <span>Edit</span>
    </button>    
</div>

openEditDialog(attachment): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AttachmentComponent, {
        data: { attachment: attachment }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
        if(result){
            this.doc = result;
        }
    });
}

editAttachmentNote(attachment) {
    this.openEditDialog(attachment);
}
```

=== attachment component ===

```
export class AttachmentUploadComponent {
      constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AttachmentComponent>,
                @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
                private http: HttpClient) {

          if(!data.attachment) {
               data.attachment = new AttachmentDto();
               this.disableUpload  = false;
          }
          else {
               this.disableUpload  = true;
          }
      }
     onCancelClick() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
     }
}

<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="data.attachment.note" [disabled]="!fileToUpload && !disableUpload" matInput matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="1" matAutosizeMaxRows="3" placeholder="Note">
    </textarea>
</mat-form-field>

<button fxFlex="nogrow" mat-button (click)="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
<button *ngIf="disableUpload" fxFlex="nogrow" mat-button cdkFocusInitial (click)="updateAttachmentNote()">
    Update
</button>
```

But here what I am seeing is when I edit data in the Dialog box, data is automatically updating in the table which I am able to see in the background.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: can you add your both components code?

Comment: yup. the code has been added

Comment: @PiyaModi did you check my answer?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal - Sorry for late reply. It works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing reference in dialog, that's why whenever there is any change in `attachment` it will reflect automatically.

To avoid this you can pass value only by modifying your code as:

```
editAttachmentNote(attachment) {
    this.openEditDialog(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attachment)));
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a variable in the method, assign it to the reference and pass in the variable to the dialog.